# How to custom keyword for spring data?

Tags: spring, spring-data

How to custom keyword for spring data? like `IsNull`,`IsNotNull`

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of the supported keywords inside method names in spring data [QueryCreation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

if you want a more specific method or a custom implementation you can use [QueryDsl or Jpa Specifications.](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)